RF Heating in a Dielectric
Trying to understand rf heating in dielectrics. Suppose I have a high frequency AC current around 50 - 100 MHz on a wire adjacent to a dielectric..
This creates an associated electric field $\mathbf{E}$.
In the dielectric there is a displacement field $\textbf{D}$
\begin{equation}
\textbf{D} = \varepsilon_{0} \textbf{E} + \textbf{P}
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon_{0}$ is the permeability of free space and $\textbf{P}$ is the polarization.
There is an associated displacement current density $\textbf{J}$
\begin{equation}
\textbf{J}=\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t} = \varepsilon_{0} \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
then by Joule's Law there should be a power density P
\begin{equation}
\textbf{E}\cdot\textbf{J}=\textbf{E}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t} = \varepsilon_{0}\textbf{E}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} + \textbf{E}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
So now my question is, if this is correct, what is the physical interpretation of $\partial\textbf{D} / \partial t$, $\partial\textbf{E}/\partial t$, and
$\partial\textbf{P}/\partial t$? I presume that the $\partial\textbf{P}/\partial t$ represents the flipping of molecular dipoles such as water to create friction. Does the $\partial\textbf{E}/\partial t$ term give rise to currents from free charges to the extent they are present in the dielectric? Thanks.


\begin{equation}
\textbf{J}=\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t} = \varepsilon_{0} \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

You've left out a term here. Typically we write the displacement current as
\begin{equation}
\textbf{J}_D=\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
and we also consider that the material may not be perfectly insulating, therefore supporting a conduction current
\begin{equation}
\textbf{J}_C=\sigma\textbf{E}
\end{equation}
And then
$$ \textbf{J} = \textbf{J}_D + \textbf{J}_C.$$
Then Joule's law becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{E}\cdot\textbf{J} &= \textbf{E}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \textbf{D}}{\partial t}+\textbf{E}\cdot\sigma\textbf{E} \\
&= \varepsilon_{0}\textbf{E}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} + \textbf{E}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t} +\textbf{E}\cdot\sigma\textbf{E}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
If we are considering plane waves (and we can decompose any wave shape into a linear combination of plane waves), then $\dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t}$ and $\dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}$ are sinusoids $\pi/2$ out of phase with $\textbf{E}$, so that the average over a full cycle of $\textbf{E}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t}$ or $\textbf{E}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \textbf{P}}{\partial t}$ is 0, and the only term that contributes to power dissipation is $\textbf{E}\cdot\sigma\textbf{E}$.

I presume that the $\partial\textbf{P}/\partial t$ represents the flipping of molecular dipoles such as water to create friction.

This is the flipping of dipoles, but it doesn't create friction. It stores energy in the electric field between the components of the dipole, and then releases it again later. There is no friction or energy dissipation implied.

Does the $\partial\textbf{E}/\partial t$ term give rise to currents from free charges to the extent they are present in the dielectric?

No, this term accounts for the displacement current that would be present even in a vacuum. Again it does not indicate power dissipation, only periodic energy storage and release.
The conduction current (if present) and any associated power dissipation, are due to the $\sigma\mathbf{E}$ term.

The Photon, thanks for your answer. How does this relate to heating from dipoles, for example in water molecules trying to align with the field and causing heat through that mechanism?

If that happens, it will appear in the equations as a non-zero $\sigma$. $sigma$ can vary with frequency --- it isn't necessarily only caused by free charge (which would have $\sigma > 0$ all the way down to DC).
